# Why is the gravitational force that is measured not doubled in the Cavendish experiment?

Tags: forces, gravity, experimental-physics, torque, rotation

[image]

Each of the smaller spheres is attracted by one bigger sphere. The rotation would work even if just one of the smaller spheres were attracted by a bigger sphere. What is the difference between these both rotations?

Let's assume we use two bigger spheres. We focus on the acceleration of one of the smaller spheres:

- first, it is accelerated by the attraction to the bigger sphere
- second, it gains an additional acceleration because the other smaller sphere is attracted to its bigger sphere, speeding up the overall rotation

Why is this not true?